# How do I replace <NA> with NaN in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Some columns in my DataFrame have instances of `<NA>` which are of type `pandas._libs.missing.NAType`.

I'd like to replace them with `NaN` using `np.nan`.

I have seen questions where the instances of `<NA>` can be replaced when using `pd.read_csv()`.

But since my Pandas DataFrame is created from a Spark DataFrame I do not use the `pd.read_csv()` function.

*Please Advise.*

Comment: I think <NA> is the integer version. I have had issues with this and found a way to just use a float.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't have any luck with the `replace` solution but was able to convert `<NA>` to np.nan by converting the column to float - `df['my_col'].astype(float)`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `replace`, but also is necessary upgrade pandas.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age':[pd.NA, 4, 8]})

df = df.replace(pd.NA, np.nan)
print (df)
   age
0  NaN
1  4.0
2  8.0
```

Comment: `TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous`

Comment: @Luke - What is your pandas version?

Comment: Pandas Version `'1.0.3'`

Comment: @Luke - seems old pandas version problem, also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60280466/merging-two-dataframes-with-pd-na-in-merge-column-yields-typeerror-boolean-val) is problem in `1.0.1`

Comment: Upgrading will fix the issue?

Comment: @Luke - I think yes.

Comment: Apologies for the delay, but `df.replace(pd.NA, np.nan)` didn't work however upgrading pandas eliminated all issues for me

Comment: Let's leave the question and answer in place for now, and decide in the future

Comment: The replace doesn't work.  I'm on pandas 1.4.0.

Comment: @jezrael The replace also doesn't work for me - any ideas? I have had to use `.convert_dtypes()` to eliminate the `object`s output of an `outer` merge.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Pandas v1.3.1` and `Numpy v1.20.3` you can use [`df.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) which do the replace when the condition is `False` like below:

```
$> df = pd.DataFrame({'age':[pd.NA, 4, 8]})
$> print(df)
    age
0  <NA>
1     4
2     8
$> print(type(df.iloc[0]['age']))
   pandas._libs.missing.NAType
$> df = df.where(pd.notnull(df), np.nan)  # Replace pd.NA, np.nan and None by np.nan
$> print(df)
   age
0  NaN
1    4
2    8
$> print(type(df.iloc[0]['age']))
   float
```

PS: You do also:

```
$> df = df.where(~pd.isna(df), np.nan)
```

Answer (score 0):

`replaсe` didn't work for me either, but following code worked for me:

```
df['my_col'].map({pd.NA: np.nan})
```